# Modeling json with blank key value pairs

Tags: c#, json, deserialization

I'm use to json with key value pairs.  I'm dealing with some json files that come across like this:

```
{
    "agents": "[{'last_name': 'Smith'}]",
    "contacts": "[]",
    "info": {
        "location ": "Your Home ",
        "more_info ": {
            "": {
                "": {
                    "_": "Custom message "
                }
            }
        },
       "last_updated": "June 2020",
        "status": {"category": "30 days", "name": "pending"},
       "active": "true"
    }
}
```

It is valid json, yet I'm not sure how to define my model so when calling JSON deseriazation, it doesn't break.

My current model looks like this:

```
public class MainDataObject
{
    public string agents {get; set;}
    public string contacts {get ;set;}
    public Info  info {get; set;}
}
public class Info
{
    public string location { get; set; }
    public string last_updated { get; set; }
    public string active {get; set;}
    public Status status {get; set;}
    public string more_info {get;set;}
    

}
public class Status
{
   public string category {get; set;}
   public string name {get; set;}
}
```

The application works fine till I come across a file containing more_info.  Most files have more_info as  "more_info" : "",   hence the reason I have it defined as a string.

Once it comes across with funky data it blows off.  Unfortunately this is coming from another vendor so I can't update their process.   Any thoughts on how to correct this?

Regards

Comment: Are you using Json.Net or System.Text.Json or ???

Comment: I think you have to write a custom converter to be able to do the traversal from `more_info` to `_` manually.

Comment: You have a weird combination of json within json, and objects with empty keys - but nonetheless a site like https://app.quicktype.io/ will quickly generate you some classes which can be used to deserialize this structure

Comment: You can also do generate the classes in Visual Studio: https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/pranayamr/generate-class-from-json-xml-in-visual-studio/

Answer (score 0):

I figured out a solution.  I don't like it but it works.  I developed two MainDataObject (MainDataObject and MainDataObjectDict) with different Info subclasses.  Info and InfoDict.

If the json deserialization errors out I import using MainDataObjectDict

The more_info withing InfoDict is described like this.

```
 public Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string,string>>> more_info { get; set; }
```

I submitted a ticket to our vendor to request they clean up their model.